# iOS7 how to understand UIPushBehavior magnitude in UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous mode?

Tags: ios7, physics, uidynamicbehavior, uidynamicanimator, uipushbehavior

I'm looking at Apple documentation for UIPushBehavior and it confuses me in instantaneous mode. I know that the acceleration formula is **Force = Mass * acceleration**. I assume that mass of a view is width*height*density(1). The documentation describes push magnitude as follows:

> The default magnitude is nil, equivalent to no force. A continuous
>   force vector with a magnitude of 1.0, applied to a 100 point x 100
>   point view whose density value is 1.0, results in view acceleration of
>   100 points / second² in the direction indicated by the angle or
>   pushDirection property.

This makes sense in terms of continuous pushing, where it provides constant acceleration. It does not say anything about intantaneous push. **How can I understand what velocity an instantaneous push of magnitude 1 will provide to a 100x100 view?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: it seem like @martin have a better answer. Please check it. I haven't had time to check it yet.

There is no acceleration in the case of an instantaneous push (`UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous`).
Then for you can't play with `magnitude` (it have no impact).
Instead you can play with the `pushDirection` vector value.
ie.:

```
pushBehavior.pushDirection = CGVectorMake(100, 100);
```

Also you could add a `UIDynamicItemBehavior` to act directly on the behavior of the object your moving in order to add some `resistance`, `friction`, ... If you want slow it down

```
UIDynamicItemBehavior *resistanceBehavior = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[view]];
resistanceBehavior.resistance = 1.0;
[self.animator addBehavior:resistanceBehavior];
```

Comment: Can you post some code with `UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous`? I upvoted your answer before testing because it would explain my problem, but `pushDirection` do not work with me... I can't succeed to make `UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous` working!

Answer (score 5):

I initially upvoted @HuguesBR answer, but now I regret because his first paragraph is wrong (can't cancel upvote after 5 minutes).

According to the documentation,

> You express a push behavior’s force vector in terms of magnitude (magnitude) and radian angle (angle). **Instead of using radian angle, you can equivalently express direction using x and y components by using the pushDirection property**. Whichever approach you use, the alternate, equivalent values update automatically.

So if you set a `pushDirection` vector to `(-1, 0)`, you'll see in debug `magnitude = 1` and `angle = PI/2`, and vice versa.

I experimented `UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous` and `UIPushBehaviorModeContinuous` modes in a small xcode project, **with no
   `UIDynamicItemBehavior` defined**. And I found strange behaviors:

`UIPushBehaviorModeInstantaneous` :

- applies just once a force to the object, the the force remains forever.
- <s>has it's `active` property set to `NO` by default.</s> Setting the `active` property to `YES` applies the force! <s>And</s>

  ```
  self.pushBehavior1.active = YES;
  self.pushBehavior1.active = YES;
  ```

  applies the force twice! (see edits)
- Once the push behavior activated, calling `self.pushBehavior1.active = NO;` does nothing.

`UIPushBehaviorModeContinuous` :

- applies each frame a force on the object. It's definitely and acceleration, but capped to a speed greater than the Instantaneous one...
- `active` property is set to `YES` by default, changing `magnitude` (or `pushDirection`) starts the movement.
- the view speed is first slower the the instant pushed one, but it quickly surpass it.

SO, to answer @AlexStone, I measured in code the speed of the moving object, and giving an **instant** push to a **100x100 view** with a **`density` of 1** and **`resistance` of 0** will give to the object a speed of **100 points / seconds** (I observed around 99.8 in fact)

**EDIT**:

After more tests in `Instantaneous` mode, it appears that `active` property is set to `YES` by default, but comes back to `NO` at the end of the frame, just after physics are simulated.
Indeed,

```
self.pushBehavior.magnitude = 1;
[self.animator addBehavior:self.pushBehavior];
```

will create a movement.
To push again, just do:

```
self.pushBehavior.active = YES;
```

Comment: I also wrote an article about this http://victorlin.me/posts/2016/04/29/how-uipushbehavior-instantaneous-mode-works, basically it's magnitude unit is momentum